# python import function from file - global name '' is not defined

Tags: python, function, file, import

I am having issue importing one function from file and executing it in another one. I cannot pass a variable 'efgh' to fun_a().

```
#cat fun_a.py 
def fun_a(abcd):
    print '%s - %s'%(abcd, efgh)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass

#python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16) [GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 
4.8.3-9)] on linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for 
more information.
>>> from fun_a import *
>>> efgh = 'test2'
>>> fun_a('test1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "fun_a.py", line 2, in fun_a
    print '%s - %s'%(abcd, efgh)
NameError: global name 'efgh' is not defined
```

I would expect the result to be 'test1 - test2'.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `global efgh` and then use it

**Ex:**

```
global efgh
efgh = 'test2'
def fun_a(abcd):
    print '%s - %s'%(abcd, efgh)

fun_a('test1')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't possibly work. `global` in Python means "within a single module"; there is no way[*] to define a global variable in the shell that would affect an imported script.

You should make `efgh` a parameter to the function.

[*] well, you could monkey-patch, but don't do that.